# WPF Task event handled in UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events

I have a Task that I've launched to handle a long running imaging operation.  Within this task, I fire an custom event.  I'm trying to subscribe to this event in my MainWindow (UI thread) to update some data on the UI.

I found what I thought was a example of how to do this ([Dispatcher to invoke event handler](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/use-wpf-dispatcher-to-invoke-event-handler-only-when-needed)), but get a compiler error (No overload for 'Imager_CameraEvent' matches delegate 'System.Action') inside the event handler at the point marked below.

Suggestions, corrections, and/or admonishments for a poor approach are welcome.

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    Imager m_imager;

    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();

        m_imager = new Imager();
        m_imager.m_cameraEvent += Imager_CameraEvent;
    }


    private void RunImager_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this task can create Camera Events
        Task ImagingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m_imager.StartImaging(m_cancelToken), m_cancelToken);
    }  


    void Imager_CameraEvent(object sender, CameraEventArgs e)
    {
        // Camera Events handled here
        if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            MainMessageWindow.AppendText(e.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(Imager_CameraEvent), sender, e);  //<-- Compiler ERROR here
        }
    } 
}
```

Imager Class (has method run in Task):

```
public delegate void CameraEventHandler(object sender, CameraEventArgs e);

public class Imager
{

    public event CameraEventHandler m_cameraEvent;
    protected virtual void OnCameraEvent(CameraEventArgs e)
    {
        m_cameraEvent(this, e);
    }



    public async void StartImaging(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        ImagingParams iParams = new ImagingParams();
        // set up iParams ...

        /// Start Imaging Task 
        Task<int> ImagingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => ImageReader_worker(iParams, cancelToken), cancelToken);

        try
        {
            imageCount = await ImagingTask;
        }       
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            OnCameraEvent(new CameraEventArgs("Imaging Cancelled"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnCameraEvent(new CameraEventArgs(ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            ImagingTask.Dispose();
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call an event from outside the class where it is declared..

Comment: Replace your line that has compilation error with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MainMessageWindow.AppendText(e.Message)));`

Comment: @sthotakura thanks!  This works.  I think I need to go back and study how to signal, using events, between classes/threads/tasks.  The approach I've used here seems messy.  Thanks again.